# Simapro dataset to ecoinvent migration fails in brightway2

Tags: brightway

I have been trying to import and link a simple Simpro CSV exported Dataset to ecoinvent. Yet having trouble as I can't the name conversion migration running.

```
sp = SimaProCSVImporter("/Users/mklarmann/Google Drive/Eaternity/Science/8.LCA/Bouillion.CSV", "Bouillion")
sp.statistics()
Extracted 1 unallocated datasets in 0.02 seconds
1 datasets
22 exchanges
22 unlinked exchanges
  Type production: 1 unique unlinked exchanges
  Type technosphere: 16 unique unlinked exchanges
```

Here is the error:

```
sp.migrate("simapro-ecoinvent-3")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-94e5fcd827af> in <module>()
----> 1 sp.migrate("simapro-ecoinvent-3")

/Users/mklarmann/Documents/workspace/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bw2io/importers/base_lci.py in migrate(self, migration_name)
    240 
    241     def migrate(self, migration_name):
--> 242         self._migrate_datasets(migration_name)
    243         self._migrate_exchanges(migration_name)
    244 

/Users/mklarmann/Documents/workspace/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bw2io/importers/base.py in _migrate_datasets(self, migration_name)
    107     def _migrate_datasets(self, migration_name):
    108         assert migration_name in migrations, \
--> 109             u"Can't find migration {}".format(migration_name)
    110         self.apply_strategy(
    111             functools.partial(migrate_datasets, migration=migration_name)

AssertionError: Can't find migration simapro-ecoinvent-3
```

any help is appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was working in an existing project. Starting from scratch (deleting all data in the Application Directory https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs ) and executing bw2setup() made it work.

Comment: To clarify what happened here: You had an older installation which, when upgraded, did not automatically install the newer migration data files (this only happens when running `bw2setup`, which aborts if an older setup has been run already. Creating a new project is the easiest way to get the newest data, but you could also delete all migrations and run `create_core_migrations` again.